# Completeness of $B(X,R)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

I'm trying to show $B(X,\mathbb R)$ the set of all bounded functions from a metric space $X$ to $\mathbb R$ is a complete metric space with respect to supremum metric, if $X$ is complete.

So I took a Cauchy sequence in $B(X,\mathbb R)$ and I'm trying to show it is convergent. My question is do we show it is pointwise convergent or uniformly?

Comment: Of course you have to show that it converges uniformly. The convergence under supremum metric is just a rewording of uniform convergence.

Comment: Note that you never used that $X$ is complete. Indeed $X$ needs only to be a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that $d(f,g)=\sup\{f(x)-g(x):x\in X\}$. If so, convergence with respect to this metric is uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you say by Supreme metric space, it does mean uninformative convergence. Of course uninformative convergence is stronger than point-wise convergence.The norm of $B(X)$ is 
$ \Vert f\Vert_{\infty} = \sup\limits_{x\in X} \vert f(x)\vert. $ So by your assumption, it is uninformative. For more information, please refer to the "Principles of real analysis, 3rd ed. C 1998" chapter 2 section 9 by "Aliprantis".

Answer (score 0):

Think about $ f_{n}(x)$ as Cauchy sequence and since your range of the functions is in $\mathbb{R}$ so they are convergent with uniform convergence because $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

Comment: R is complete, So each fn(x) converges to some f(x).
So, fn converges pointwise.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: But what am I supposed to show? Pointwise or uniform?